# JPanel draw BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a problem drawing a `BufferedImage`, it's hard to describe, so you can see it in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9K-QTKHcOYA

Here's my code:

**In the `JPanel`**

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    if(Tool.selectedTool != null)
        Tool.selectedTool.onPaintingAreaMouseMoved(e.getX(),e.getY(),z);
}

@Override
public void onPaintingAreaMouseMoved(int x, int y, int z) {
    if(clicks == 1){
        curve.controlPoints[1] = new Point(x, y, z);
        PaintingArea.paintingArea.refresh();
    }
}
```

Because of an error, I decided not to post the code of my curve class here, but I checked it and there was no mistake.

**In the `JPanel` class**

```
public void refresh(){
    axis = new int[width * height];
    for (int i = 0; i < axis.length; i++)
        axis[i] = background;
    for(int i = 0; i < Line.lines.size(); i++) {
        Point[] points = Line.lines.get(i).getPoints();
        for(int m = 0; m < points.length; m++)
            axis[points[m].x + width*points[m].y] = 0;
    }
    repaint();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setSize(width,height);
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    image.setRGB(0,0, width, height, axis,0, 1);
    g.drawImage(image,0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),null);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  The section [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how to perform custom painting.

Comment: i do not use netbeans

Comment: maybe i should upload the code of the Line.getPoints() method, too?

Comment: *"maybe i should upload the code of the Line.getPoints() method, too?"* The best thing to do would be to add a [mre].

Comment: There are at least two problems in the `paintComponent` method. 1) `setSize(width,height);` this might change the size of the drawing area which will invoke a call to `repaint()` which will cause an infinite loop. 2) `g.drawImage(image,0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),null);` A `JPanel` **is an** `ImageObserver` so that should instead (of the `null`) be `g.drawImage(image,0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),this);`. --- if neither change fixes the problem, post a MRE and I'll look at it more closely.

Comment: .. 3) And shorter, `g.drawImage(image,0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),this);` could be `g.drawImage(image,0,0,this);`.

Comment: thanks for your help, tried your advices but it didint change anything. if you want, here is the code of the Line.getPoints() class:

Comment: Those are not answers, and even if the code snippets were included in the question, they would not form a MRE as I suggested.  I am voting to close. **Please [edit] the question to add a [mre].** If there is anything in it you do not understand, ask, but please stop wasting time adding random, uncompilable code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(new PaintingArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(panel);
    pack();
    setSize(800,700);
    setVisible(true);
```